# Simple way to use bigquery result in python where the query return only one result

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm simply trying to get one data from bigquery from python.
Below is the query

```
select max(date) from `x.x.table_name`
```

all the requirements to access bigquery in python is done, and I run the query as below

```
query_job = client.query('select max(date) from `x.x.table_name`')
```

and it returns google.cloud.bigquery.job.query.QueryJob object.
Is there a quick way to get the result rather than going through the RowIterator, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

result() on a QueryJob will wait for the result of the job and return iterator so then you can use next():

```py
    result = query_job.result()
    row = next(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `google.cloud.bigquery.job.query.QueryJob` object to a pandas dataframe using [to_dataframe()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.to_dataframe). When converted you can use pandas to manipulate your data.

**See code below:**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

sql = """
    SELECT *
    FROM `my-project-id.my-dataset.myTable`
"""

query_job = client.query(sql)
df = query_job.to_dataframe()

print("Query results:")
print(df)
print("\nGet 1st row values")
print(df.iloc[0])
```

**Testing:**

[image]

You can also use [to_arrow()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.to_arrow) and [to_geodataframe()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.to_geodataframe) if you are more comfortable at manipulating these data types.